# The type or namespace name 'IPAddress' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a Xamarin.Forms application and have added a PCL project into my main solution in Visual Studio 2013.  I'm having problems with using several standard .net classes.  Here's a list:

```
System.Net.IPAddress
System.Net.IPEndPoint
System.Net.WebClient
System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
System.Timers.Timer
System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs
System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnicastIPAddressInformation
```

My question is: How do I figure out which of the above are compatable with a Xamarin.Forms app, and how do I get them to work in my project/solution?

I've contacted Xamarin support, but get vague help and not specifics...

Does anybody have a good strategy for figuring out what classes are supported and what .dlls are needed in order to use them with a Xamarin.Forms project?

Thanks a bunch for your help.

PS:  I've been given the following sites for reference, but they don't seem to have any concise information:

[What is supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[NuGet package info](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22BCL%22)

Comment: _"I've contacted Xamarin support, but get vague help and not specifics..."_ what did the Xamarin support tell you?

Comment: If you take a look at the [System.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation, you'll notice that IPAddress, IPEndPoint and WebClient aren't supported by the PCL. You can tell whether PCL supports the class or not by checking if [this icon](http://i.imgur.com/fgkFVES.png) exists next to it. See the section _Finding the Supported Members in Reference Documentation_ in your "What is supported" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional e-mail from Xamarin Support, and comments on my additional posting, it appears that MS is quite behind in supporting all of their classes via PCL.  Some are supported, but not all by a long shot.

Anyway, in order to use my existing code, I would need to put the source .cs files that I would otherwise be using to create my new PCL project directly in the .iOS project and in the .droid project and recompile that way.

This basically defeats the advantage of using a PCL, but does provide an alternative that allows me to use most of my code unchanged.  It would just be nicer if all the xamarin libraries were available as PCLs..  Oh well, eventually MS will catch up and get all of their PCLs up to date so that we can use our custom PCLs more often, instead of having to duplicate code all over the place. (Maintenance Nightmare)...

Anyway, thanks to all for the help.

(Working on the bleeding edge of technology is sometimes painful...  But that's why we make the big bucks !!!)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't understand what Portable Class Libraries actually are.  When you create a PCL, the subset of the .Net Framework classes that are available for you to use depends on what profile you choose.  A profile are the platforms your PCL can support.  In Xamarin, the default profile is Profile 78. Profile 78 supports .NET 4.5, WP8, Win8, WP Silverlight 8, Win Store 8, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS. So the classes that are available to you are the classes that are platform independent, that run on ALL platforms in profile 78.

Example: Take a look at the implementation of [System.Net.IPAddress](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs).  The implementation makes use of [Sockets](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,c84007a498b38b5f).  Upon further inspection of this implementation, you can see that that `System.Net.Sockets` is nothing more than a .NET wrapper around the [WinSock API](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958787.aspx).  The WinSock API is a Windows only DLL that is specific to the Windows operating family (ws2_32.dll).  So, you can now see that System.Net.IPAddress are high level abstractions of Windows Socks (built for the Windows Platform).  Since the ws2_32.dll does not exist in Android, nor iOS, etc, this API won't be available to you because Profile 78 specifies that we need to support other non-windows platforms.

Another example is System.Drawing.Bitmap.  That's just a .NET wrapper around [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is based on the Win32 API.  Of course Win32 is not available on non-windows platforms (even Windows Phone), which is why you won't see it in a PCL.

Now with that being said, you may think that PCLs are restrictive, but you can create a good PCL library if you think [about them the right way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx).  You can also use patterns like Dependency Injection and [Bait and Switch](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/).

So in short, don't count on Microsoft "adding support for all the base class libraries" because that's not what PCLs are.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `System.Net.IpAddress` in your Xamarin.Forms PCL by using DependancyService. Make an interface in PCL and declare a method "GetIpAddress" in it. Then , in android /iOS project, you can implement that interface in platform specific project and easily access `System.Net.IpAddress.` After that, Call DependancyService from PCL project to get the result which is IPAddress of your desire.

Cheers !!!